# Simplest way to add a partial page cut in epson printer using javascript and HTML

Tags: epson

I am trying to introduce a partial page cut when my Epson TM-T82 printer prints a HTML webpage. Is there a way by which I can add a partial page cut, let's say, between two divs of the same HTML page simply by writing a javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

You can create page breaks with CSS.

Add these to your html style:

```
@media all {
    .page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

And then you can create Page Breaks between your divs like this:

```
<div class="page-break"></div>
```

[Source](https://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks)

Comment: I use "pdfmake" (https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) to create the printed result as a PDF file. So I use a page break there:


{
                image: 'cutHereLine',
                width: pageWidth - 20,
                alignment: 'center',
                margin: [5, 0, 5, 0],
                pageBreak: (i === itemsArrayLength - 1) ? '' : 'after',
              }


However, this does not result in an automatic cut of the paper. Is this possible inside a PDF?